# Django: IntegrityError when migrating after adding foreign key field

Tags: django, django-models

I have three models as follows in a Django app named `markets`:

```
class Market(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    current_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0.50)
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    shares_yes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    shares_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    b = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    cost_function = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    open = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title[:50]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('market_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Price(models.Model):
    market = models.ForeignKey(
        Market, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='prices', 
        default=None)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, 
        decimal_places=2, 
        default=0.50)
    price_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=now,
        blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.price)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('market_list')

class Share(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='user_shares', 
        default=None)
    market = models.ForeignKey(
        Market, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='market_shares', 
        default=None)
    share = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=now, 
        blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.share)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('market_list')
```

I would like to add the following foreign key field to the `Price` model:

```
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name='user_prices', 
            default=None)
```

When I run `makemigrations` on `markets`, there's no issue. But when I try to actually `migrate` the database, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "user_id" contains null values
```

Why is that? I had no issues adding a user field to the `Share` model, so am not clear on why I run into problems when also looking to add it to `Price`.

Comment: Well the problem is that a foreignkey is by default non-null, but you provide `None` as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run `makemigrations` on markets, there's no issue. But when I try
>   to actually migrate the database, I get the following error:
>
> ```
> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "user_id" contains null values
> ```
>
> Why is that?

A `ForeignKey` is by default non-NULLable. But you specify a `default=None`. The migraiton thus aims to insert `NULL` for the existing records, and that will fail.

You can make your `ForeignKey` nullable with:

```
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name='user_prices',
            null=True,
            default=None
    )
```

You will need to remove (or alter) the migration file, and recreate a migration file.

Another way to resolving this is providing a `CustomUser` object to which you link the existing records, with that user.

> **Note**: usually it is better to use [**`get_user_model()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) instead of providing the user model as a reference or string. If you later change your mind, you can alter the setting, and then all `ForeignKey`s will be remapped on the new user model.